# Numpy inconsistent results with Pandas and missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, missing-data

Why does `numpy` return different results with missing values when using a Pandas series compared to accessing the series' values as in the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6]))
np.sum(data['a'])

#12.0

np.sum(data['a'].values)
#nan
```

Comment: Based on the answer by @coldspeed, this isn't quite a duplicate. I'm willing to remove it though if it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `np.sum` on a pandas Series delegates to `Series.sum`, which ignores NaNs when computing the sum (BY DEFAULT).

```
data['a'].sum()
# 12.0

np.sum(data['a'])
# 12.0
```

You can see this from the source code of `np.sum`:

```
np.sum??

def sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue, initial=np._NoValue):
    ...
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
```

Taking a look at the source code for `_wrapreduction`, we see:

```
np.core.fromnumeric._wrapreduction??

def _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs):
    ...
    if type(obj) is not mu.ndarray:
        try:
            reduction = getattr(obj, method)   # get reference to Series.add
```

`reduction` is then finally called at the end of the function:

```
            return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
```

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. Was just copying over the `numpy` source haha. +1

Comment: Thanks! This applies to other `numpy` functions acting on Pandas series as well (such as `mean`, `min`, `max`, `median`, etc.)?

Comment: @willk Yes, most ufuncs, actually. There might be exceptions that I am not aware of though.

Comment: There is a numpy function for summing up arrays with NaN: numpy.nansum():  Function is used when we want to compute the sum of array elements over a given axis treating Not a Numbers (NaNs) as zero.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the safest option is to use `data['a'].sum(skipna=True)` to be explicit. Or use the `np.nansum` function.

Comment: @willk Try here for a list of nan functions https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py

Comment: @willk No need to be explicit, that is default behaviour with most pandas reduction functions.